# The query does not work on .net but it works on sql management studio

Tags: sql, .net, web, parameters, command

When I run the query with sql management studio, I get results, but when I run it with .net application, my query does not work.

`

```
public static void findUser_P(string mail, string password)
        {
            using (var connection = GetSqlConnection())
            {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "select * from [dbo].[User] where UserName=@mail and Password=@password";
                    SqlCommand fcommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    fcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                    fcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", mail);
                    SqlDataReader reader = fcommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    // read data for single/first record here
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString());
                }
                    reader.Close();

            }
           
        }`
```

`

Comment: The query returns nothing or it throws an exception? Also, have you tried setting a breakpoint here `SqlDataReader reader = fcommand.ExecuteReader();` to see what the actual query looks like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.